# Java - Hibernate not returning special characters on select query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, character-encoding

I am doing a query like this:

```
Query query = PlatoonApp.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.type1 LIKE ? or c.type2 LIKE ? or c.type3 LIKE ?" +
                " or c.type4 LIKE ? ORDER BY c.type", Client.class);

        query.setParameter(1, legalStrQuery + "%");
        query.setParameter(2, legalStrQuery + "%");
        query.setParameter(3, individualStrQuery + "%");
        query.setParameter(4, individualStrQuery + "%");

        query.setFirstResult(startPosition);

        if (maxResults != 0)
            query.setMaxResults(maxResults);

        return (List<Client>) query.getResultList();
```

This is the query. I have some rows with information using "´", "~" and these characters are getting replaced. Why is it happening?

Comment: @Nambari with another characters. When I execute the SELECT in the mysql command line the characters com out as they should.

Comment: What is the character encoding defined in hibernate-cfg.xml?

Comment: @Nambari the encoding is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Escape the single quote by adding another single quote before it, e.g. `'` would become `''`.

I don't think that the `~` is an illegal character, it's just the single quote that's hanging you up.

Note: I think you can replace all of the single quotes with the following regex, `(?!<')['](?!')` so you can do something like..

```
stringInstance.replaceAll( "(?!<')['](?!')", "''" );
```